# remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size (2.00 GiB)error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)

Tags: r, github

remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size (2.00 GiB)error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)

Hello,

I am hoping for help in resolving this error I get when trying to establish a new github repo for an existing R project. This is a big project and I'd really like to establish a github workflow for it. I have other repos that I interact with successfully, but this one I cannot get to work.

I think it is related to the fact that the files are too big to upload all at once - there are large databases and spatial files. I have tried making the repo from within RStudio using the usethis package, I have also tried the method described here: https://youtu.be/sxErFMF7BJY

I also tried the solution described here: [How do I initialize a git repository to an already existing program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190791/how-do-i-initialize-a-git-repository-to-an-already-existing-program)

I am new to using version control and I appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing your repository by adding all files in a single commit, try adding them gradually in multiple smaller commits.
Using the command line, push commits individually:

```
git push <remotename> <commit SHA>:<branch>
```

- The bad: the intermediate commits likely won't represent a working project state
- The good: GitHub might accept the smaller commits.

I found this solution from [reddit user triplesea](https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/otlucm/comment/h7120s0/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)